# My PHP file doesn't receive data from my android app using POST method

Tags: php, android

I have a problem with php file when it should receive some data form my android app. I'm using POST method and I can't figure it out why it doesn't work. I've tried searching for answers but everything I tried, it doesn' work. First, I used URLConnection class for connection with server, and after that, I tried with HttpURLConnection, but still doesn't work. I want to transfer data to server exclusively with the POST method, not GET. Could anyone explane me what I'm doing wrong, or did I forget something to add or configure?

Comment: It's impossible for anyone to answer this question if you don't post the relevant code segment.  Also, it would be helpful to know what you mean by 'it doesn't work'.  Are you receiving an error?  Or ?

Comment: you should show us some code, otherwise we might need a wizard to tell you what you are doing wrong

Comment: I'm sorry guys, I found what a problem was. I called getInputStream method before I send data to server using OutputStreamWriter. I felt helpless so I asked here for help. Once again, I'm sorry and thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like this :
            `URL url = new URL("your_url_here");
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setConnectTimeout(10000);
            connection.setReadTimeout(10000);
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            connection.connect();
            byte[] output = "your data to send here".getBytes("UTF-8");
            OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
            os.write(output);
            os.flush();
            os.close();`

Comment: I found what a problem was. Thank you anyway.